# Catch copy event android

Tags: android, dictionary, copy, selected, instant

I am programming a dictionary which has Instant lookup function. I wanna when I selected text and copy it, a popup is displayed (display this text and meaning of it). Firstly, I wanna display selected text.
Any idea and advice.
You can view this apps: [QuickDict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vn.com.itisus.android.quickdictionary&hl=vi)
I really like it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using API level 11 (3.0) or above, then you can use addPrimaryClipChangedListener which is documented [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) and there is some example usage [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html).